# Page Manager fails when accessing structure pages

Tags: nodes, 9

When I go to Admin/Structure/Pages, the following error occurs:

> InvalidArgumentException: The internal path component
> 'https://dssm.vegas/civicrm/contribute/transact' is external. You are
> not allowed to specify an external URL together with internal:/. in
> Drupal\Core\Url::fromInternalUri() (line 420 of
> core/lib/Drupal/Core/Url.php).

I either need assistance in removing the error or instruction as to where I can delete the latest page I tried to add to the site without this interface.

Comment: If you have access to the database, you could run `SELECT MAX(nid) FROM node;` to get the ID of the page you added most recently. If you then go to https://yoursite.com/node/ID/edit it will open the page in the page editor, and a delete link will be available at the bottom of the form.

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try.

Comment: Well, gave it a go and no resolution after deleting the blank page at that node. I did learn a new trick and I thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

After a backup of the database...

First, I searched the MySQL database for records that had both "contribute" & "transact".

Next: Suspecting the **drpl_router** table, I found one of the two entries, one with "page_manager" in it and the name of the form created before the crash. Deleted that record. Found similar in the **drpl_config** table and deleted that.

Reloaded the page, went back to Admin/Structure/Pages and was able to load the page manager.

Hope this helps someone.